# How to run a single thread 7z benchmarking using the command line?

Tags: 7zip

I can run "7z -b" for multi threading benchmark and compare results between platforms such as Windows and Linux. But how to compare single thread 7z benchmark on Ubuntu? :)

I found no documentation in 7z -h and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/7z.1.html about restricting 7z -b to run only in single thread.

I would love to compare the results with Windows just for checking the Intel Haswell Turbo Boost performance whether is working or not on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks in advanced. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this command:

```
7z b -mmt1
```

You can read about it here:
http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/bench.htm

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
taskset -c cpu_num 7z b -mmt1
```